# Classic ASP .CopyFile "Permission Denied" error on Windows Server 2008, IIS 7

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, windows-server-2008, filesystemobject

We are upgrading our intranet web server from a Windows Server 2000, IIS 4 environment to Windows Server 2008, IIS 7 environment.  As part of the upgrade, I'm modifying a classic ASP application to make it work in the new environment.

One of the pages attempts to create a new Word file by copying a template file (.dot) into a Word file (.doc) in the same directory on the web server, using the command:

```
fs.CopyFile docRoot & templateFile,docRoot & docName, true
```

Note - docRoot is an absolute path, not a virtual path.

The destination folder is set to have full permissions for:

- Everyone
- Administrators
- IUSR
- IWAM accounts

I still get the following error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0046' 

Permission denied
```

Just wondering if anyone had seen this, and if there was a workaround available.  (I attempted to set a default application user to use my permissions, but that didn't work, either...)

Comment: Rafael - adding SYSTEM seemed to do the trick.  Running into another issue now (Insufficient memory), but I want to research it thoroughly before bringing it back here as a question...

Comment: Ok good luck... Good to see that my answer works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem in Windows 2008 /2008 R2 is the UAC service that born in Vista era. 
secures everything in inetpub directory 
... as a workarround try to put your file in Users/Public/ directory, modify your path and try again.

another thing you can try is giving file's total control privileges to the IIS_WPG group.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link and give permission to internet Guest User.

http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/files/directories-fso/could-i-get-some-help-working-with-files-using-filesystemobject.html